# Issues in iterating through multiple foreach loops

Tags: c#, sql, c#-4.0, ado.net

I have multiple `foreach` loops through which i am fetching the work history , education history of the users from Facebook and inserting these into a database:

```
Result soap = serializer.Deserialize<Result>(ser);
foreach (var item in soap.data)
{
    int length = item.education_history.Length;
    int lenght2 = item.work_history.Length;

    foreach (var edu in item.education_history)
    {
        length--; 
        ftr = ftr + "," + edu.name.ToString();
    }

    foreach (var wrk in item.work_history)
    {
        lenght2--;
        ftr1 = ftr1 + "," + wrk.company_name.ToString();
    }

    string str1 = "Insert into [Snaps] (Loc_city,Loc_state,Loc_country,Edu_Hist1,Work_Hist1) values ('" + item.current_location.city.ToString() + "','" + item.current_location.state.ToString() + "','" + item.current_location.country.ToString() + "','" + ftr + "','" + ftr1 + "')";
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(str1, con);
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

PS: This code is just for testing purposes thus not used parameterized sql query

The problem i am encountering is that when i am calculating the values of `ftr` and  `ftr1` of the first item in the parent foreach loop

```
foreach (var item in soap.data)
```

and when i insert these values into the database it appends the second array index in `item` and saves it in the database. Also the values of `ftr` and `ftr1` are not getting refreshed it appends the new values with the previous ones

What am i doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `ftr` and `ftr1` variables are **not being reset after each iteration in the main loop**, hence the values keep being concatenated to them.

One solution would be to set both `ftr` and `ftr1` to `null` or empty strings at the end of the main loop:

```
foreach (var item in soap.data)
{
    foreach (var edu in item.education_history)
    {
        // ...
    }

    foreach (var wrk in item.work_history)
    {
        // ...
    }

    // ...

    ftr = null;
    ftr1 = null;
}
```

However, a simpler approach would be to use the [Enumerable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) method in LINQ to extract the lists of values from the `education_history` and `work_history` arrays and use [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) to concatenate them into two strings:

```
foreach (var item in soap.data)
{
    var educationNames = item.education_history.Select(i => i.name.ToString());
    var ftr = String.Join(",", educationNames);

    var previousCompaniesNames = item.work_history.Select(i => i.company_name.ToString());
    var ftr1 = String.Join(",", previousCompaniesNames);

    var statement = "INSERT INTO [Snaps] (Loc_city,Loc_state,Loc_country,Edu_Hist1,Work_Hist1) VALUES (@city, @state, @country, @educationNames, @previousCompaniesNames)";
    var command = new SqlCommand(statement, con);
    command.Parameters.Add("@city", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = item.current_location.city.ToString();
    command.Parameters.Add("@state", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = item.current_location.state.ToString();
    command.Parameters.Add("@country", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = item.current_location.country.ToString();
    command.Parameters.Add("@educationNames", SqlDbType.VarChar, 4000).Value = ftr
    command.Parameters.Add("@previousCompaniesNames", SqlDbType.VarChar, 4000).Value = ftr1
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();    
}
```

This way the `ftr` and `ftr1` variables are **declared at each iteration**, so there's no need to manually reset their value.

Comment: @vini Which solution have you implemented?

Comment: The second one the records get inserted multiple times

Comment: the problem is that when the sql query is executed..it somehow is inserting data which is present in second index of item array as specified in ques...appended with first index values.

Comment: I did the same thing my friend. I dun knw why its appending the second index values when its not even going to the second index. I am checking the results by debugging every statement. The values are fine in the variables. But when i stop my debugging at the execution of command.ExecuteNonQuery and check my table I get multiple table entries.

Answer (score 0):

> ftr and ftr1 are not getting refreshed it appends the new values with
>   the previous ones

yes you are not refreshing it, if you want to use new values for each iteration then use

```
ftr = "";
ftr1 = "";
```

Comment: Put these lines at the beginning of the first loop.